# How to get a specific string value out of a json response from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data structure and I can't extract the right value:

```
users
    private
        userID
            birthday: "birthdayValue"
            username: "nathan"
            firstName: "Nathan"
            etc...
```

I'm making a search feature in my app to search for users via their username through the firebase realtime database:

```
let reference = Database.database().reference()
    if(searchText != ""){
        reference.child("users").child("private").queryOrdered(byChild:  "username").queryStarting(atValue: searchText).queryEnding(atValue: searchText + "\u{f8ff}").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull{
                    //handles errors
                    return
                }
                else{
                if let user = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                    for child in user{
                        print(child.key)
                        print(child.value)
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        //null
                    }
                }
            })
```

at the moment the two print statements are printing these two results in the console every time I search:

```
wnszfmHilqNl6PG9khWtWkKUPtF3
{
    birthday = 100;
    dateCreated = "1579543450313.94";
    description = nil;
    email = "email@email.com";
    firstName = Nathan;
    instagramLink = nil;
    lastLogin = "1579543450313.988";
    lastName = Ellis;
    profilePicURL = "url";
    twitchLink = nil;
    username = nathan;
    youtubeLink = nil;
}
```

Which is expected, it prints the usersID (the key) and the value of the snapshot as a NSDictonary. I'm only interested in getting the username, nothing else. How would I extract the username out of this firebase snapshot so I can add their username as a string to an array for my search controller?

Obviously it needs to be dynamic as the userID will always be different.

Would I need to change my data model?

Comment: What is your data model exactly? Are you using structs that conform to `Codable` ?

Comment: I'm not using a data model, I just want to get the username out of the snapshot I receive and add it to a simeple array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `child.value` seems to be a dictionary as well, so you can access it by:

```
if let valueDict = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
  if let username = valueDict["username"] as? String {
      // append username to results
      print(username)
  }

}
```

Comment: @NathanEllis are you sure you're casting child.value to dictionary and subscripting that?

Comment: I assume that code will go into the for loop, if so then yes. Nothing comes out of it. Remember my snapshot data that comes out is nested into the userID, which is probs the problem

Answer (score 0):

To print just the username, the smallest possible change is:

```
print(resultsLocalArray["username"])
```

This will fine, but will still retrieve the entire user node to the client, which uses more bandwidth than strictly needed.

If you find yourself frequently needing just the `username` of a user, or maybe even a list of `username` values across users, you might want to consider storing a node with just user names. So something like:

```
users
    userID: "nathan"
```

But in your current setup you only retrieve the node for a single user, so I doubt the bandwidth savings are worth the additional complexity.

Comment: thats what i thought of doing but I need their profile picture url along with it for the table view

Comment: when I do your way it also passes as nil?

Comment: resultsLocalArray isn't filled with anything yet...I just took it out my code to be less confusing, still can't retrieve the username string from it.